# get current logged in user role

Tags: user-roles

I have created new user from admin > permission > user .

Now I want to get current user permission role

```
 $roleId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
 $role = Mage::getSingleton('customer/group')->load($roleId)->getData('customer_group_code');
 $role = strtolower($role);
```

but its now working

Comment: I tried that code snippet and it's working. What do you mean by 'not working'?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question, but it seem as you created an "admin user" and not a "customer".

To get an admin user role try (assuming that user is log in)

```
$admin_user_session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$adminuserId = $admin_user_session->getUser()->getUserId();
$role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($adminuserId)->getRole()->getData();
```

See [Magento: How to get user role from user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796128/magento-how-to-get-user-role-from-user-id)